Change Outliner area size via python
Looking for a way to write a toggler to quickly compress and expand the Outliner to the right edge of the screen and back.
It seems that "bpy.ops.screen.area_move()" operator can be used for this purpose. But I haven't managed to pass the correct context to this operator yet.
Here is the code i use:
def execute(self, context):
    # get outliner window
    win = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0]
    screen = win.screen
    area = next(area for area in screen.areas if area.type == "OUTLINER")
    override = {
    "window": win,
    "screen": screen,
    "area": area
    }
    bpy.ops.screen.area_move(override, x=10, y=10, delta=10)
    return {'FINISHED'}

Ends with an error: "Operator bpy.ops.screen.area_move.poll() failed, context is incorrect"
